# How to add comments to a WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I add comments to my WordPress theme. I tried `<?php comment_form(); ?>` but it doesn't give any output. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just add the following line

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

inside your `single.php` where you want to add/display the comments template. This will add/include the `comments.php` file in the `single` template and make sure that `comments.php` is also available in your theme folder.

Also you can use [Disqus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comment-system/) wordpress plugin, it's a very nice plugin.

**References:** [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template) and a [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/unraveling-the-secrets-of-wordpress-commentsphp-file/).

Comment: A litte hint : even if you don't create the comments.php file wordpress will generate all the needed data to have a working comment module. But you'll have to create a comments.php to apply your site's template

Comment: Thanks @Sam. Yes, you are right and you don't need to do that unless you want to override the default one.